# How to create custom textfield and textview

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, textview, textfield

How to create the textfield has show in below figure

in below figure Address is an custom textview.

[image: Create the custom Textfield with only one single line.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
txt_Username = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,40,self.view.frame.size.width/2,32)];
txt_Username.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
txt_Username.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
txt_Username.placeholder = @"PlacceHolder";
txt_Username.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
txt_Username.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
txt_Username.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
txt_Username.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
txt_Username.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
txt_Username.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
[txt_Username setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
txt_Username.leftView= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"user"]];

txt_Username.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
[txt_Username setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
UIView *demoLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(txt_Username.frame.origin.x
                                                            , txt_Username.frame.origin.y+txt_Username.frame.size.height
                                                            , txt_Username.frame.size.width, 1)];
[demoLine setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];    
[self.view addSubview:demoLine];
```

Try this It will helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Change your textfield border style to  Transparent one (most left in Attribute Inspector). Use a image for the line in UIImageView. Above this image place your textfield. Or instead of using image for the line, draw the line. Line drawing code is here :

```
-(void)drawLine:(CGFloat)fromX fromY:(CGFloat)fromY toX:(CGFloat)toX toY:(CGFloat)toY width:(CGFloat)width color:(UIColor *)color
{
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(fromX, fromY)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(toX, toY)];

    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = [color CGColor];
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = width;
    shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
}
```

Better if you use avoid line drawing and stick to images.